# page.jsp does not work

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have a tomcat - spring mvc - jsp application.

I have discovered that a page called `page.jsp` is not found (404). But if I called `page2.jsp` then it just works fine.

Is it a bug or is it written somewhere in the spec that you can't call a jsp file `page`?

(BTW, I called it page because it is a part of the system that allows admins to administer pages. I.e. it is a name I really wanted - although I will readily switch to what works)

Comment: You need to post more info. springmvc conf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 means 404, jsp is simply not there. This is tomcat, so go to webapps directory, and look into directory your war is unpacked into. Look for your JSPs.

Possible reasons for 404:

1. File is not there. Failed to package it
2. File is there, but called PAGE.JSP. URLs after domain name are case-sensitive.
3. Some funny filter installed in Tomcat that really prohibits page.jsp from being accessed. Unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Check your spring configuration file for URL mapping or there may be a wrong call to page.jsp from a controller.